# How to get BoundingSphere from Scene Primitive

Tags: cesiumjs

In Cesium i would like the camera to fly to the bounding sphere of the scene primitive so that i can see the whole building from a singular spot. Extra question: will flying to the bounding sphere show me whole building from a single spot NO MATTER the size of the `<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>` because it is a responsive container

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a scene primitive is already like a boundingsphere and we can fly to it as long as it is a tileset by doing this `Camera.flyTo(tileset)`

Comment: flyTo API does not support any primitive.